# leave or left in the situation mentioned below

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, american-english, present-tense, spoken-english

I was talking to my co-worker about another annoying co-worker. My co-worker asked, "Is she still here?" referring to that annoying co-worker.

I said,
"I don't know but I wish she left."

Now, I Immediately knew that I have made an error. But I am still not able to figure out how I should've constructed this sentence to imply that I wanted that coworker gone at that time I was having this conversation.

I am thinking maybe something like,

"I don't know but I wish she leave."

"I don't know but I wish she leave *by now*."

"I don't know but I wish she has left."

"I don't know but I wish she has left *by now*."

Is anyone of this correct? Do you think there's a better way of saying this exact same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rather odd to use "wish" for events that are in that past.  You don't say

> I wish she left.

You can wish for future events, using conditional

> I wish she would leave.

But this doesn't solve your problem since you don't know if she is here now or not.  Instead you can *hope* for a current state.

> Is she still here?
>
> I don't know, but I hope she isn't.

> I hope she has left already.